# ExtJS 5: Using lookupReference in ViewController beforeInit

Tags: extjs, viewcontroller, extjs5

I'm trying to look up a reference to one of my components in the ViewController's `beforeInit`, so I can set some variables on `myComponent` before it's created, but `lookupReference` does not find my component in the beforeInit call... it's found in the ViewController's init method, but I'm assuming because the view hasn't actually been rendered, the reference hasn't been created.

So I figured I'd try `initComponent`, but once again, the lookupReference doesn't work in there... I know I could create an itemId and look for this in initComponent, but that's last resort for me... I'd rather use the reference. See [this Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nvs) example and code:

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.define('MyViewController', {
      extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
      alias: 'controller.myview',

      beforeInit: function() {
        console.log('beforeInit: I want this to exist before myComponent is rendered', this.lookupReference('myComponent'));
      },

      init: function() {
        console.log('init', this.lookupReference('myComponent'));
      }
    });
    Ext.define('MyView', {
      extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
      controller: 'myview',
      title: 'My View',
      height: 400,
      width: 400,
      items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        reference: 'myComponent',
        fieldLabel: 'My Component'
      }],
      initComponent: function() {
        // I want this to happen before myComponent is rendered
        console.log('initComponent: I want this to exist before myComponent is rendered', this.lookupReference('myComponent'));
        this.callParent();
        console.log('initComponent callParent', this.lookupReference('myComponent'));
      }
    });
    Ext.create('MyView', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
  }
});
```

Does anyone have any guidance on how to accomplish something like this?

Comment: beforeInit is called before the initComponent of the view. And references are applied only after the initComponent.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I gathered... and it looks like I was wrong about itemId, as that falls under the same scenario.  So the question remains, how would one do this?  I have a working solution of creating my items in the `beforeInit` method, then storing them as private variables, but I'm wondering what the Ext way is.

Comment: What kind of variables are you trying to set? Can they not be passed to the view during creation?

Comment: I'll come up with a better example soon... I did have a discussion with a user over on the [Sencha forums](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301783-Using-lookupReference-in-ViewController-beforeInit), if you'd like to check that out.